# Roots of complex polynomial have modulus less than 1

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $0<a_0<a_1<...<a_n$, $a_i\in \mathbb R$.
I need to show that if $$a_0+a_1z+...+a_nz^n=0$$ then $|z|<1$.
Any hints? I don’t know how to begin.

I can’t use Rouche’s theorem as it wasn’t introduced in the classes yet, and the answer to the duplicated question shown only that $|z|\leq1$, but I don’t know how to rule out the $|z|=1$ case.

Comment: You want to use Rouche's Theorem of course, but it barely doesn't work. The trick is to slightly modify your function. The details can be found in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Rouche’s theorem has not been introduced in the classes yet, so I hoped for a more elementary approach

Comment: then please edit the post with more details, any attempts you've made, etc and appeal to have it re-opened.

Comment: To rule out $|z|=1$ note that equality happens in the triangle inequality only if the respective complex numbers have all the same argument ($|a_1+a_2+... a_k| = |a_1|+..|a_k|$ means $a_k=r_ke^{i\alpha}$) for same $\alpha$, so checking the linked answer you will note that you need a root $z$ on the unit circle to have same argument as $a_0$, so it would have to be $1$ but plainly $1$ is not a root of the original equation